# Concat in loadscript between SQL statements

Tags: qliksense

Hej folks,

it is driving me crazy. I'll try to concat some values from one table to use it in a where clause in another statement. It's like this script.

```
LIB CONNECT TO 'MSSQLSERVER';

TempTab:
Load KST;
SQL SELECT KST FROM vKST WHERE Region = 'Driver';

Let Test = Concat(distinct KST, ',');

drop Table TempTab;

// ...

LIB CONNECT TO 'ORACLESERVER';

Foo:
Load *;
SQL SELECT Value FROM KSTvalues WHERE KST IN ($(Test));
```

My problem is that the variable "Test" is only calculated to null. Has anyone a working idea for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `Concat` function should be used in context of a table in order to get all the values from a field.

So to get all values you'll have to load them in a temp table first and in it to perform the concatenation. And then use variable to get the resulted field value.

Have a look at the script below. The concatenation is performed in `TempTable` and then using [peek](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2020/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/InterRecordFunctions/Peek.htm) function to get the value of `ConcatField` into `vConcatValues` variable (im dropping the `TempTable` at the end because its not needed once the variable is populated)

`TempTable` will have the following content:

[image: Table content]

And `vConcatValues` will be:

[image: Variable content]

```
RawData:
Load * inline [
Values
Value1
Value1
Value2
Value3
Value4
Value5
];


TempTable:
Load
  Concat(distinct Values, ',') as ConcatField
Resident
  RawData
;

let vConcatValues = peek('ConcatField');

// We dont need the TempTable anymore and can be dropped
Drop Table TempTable;
```

P.S. probably the sql clause will raise an error, because the values will not be defined as strings. In this case you can use something like this:

```
TempTable:
Load
  Concat(distinct Values, '","') as ConcatField
Resident
  Raw
;
```

Using `","` as separator will result in `Value1","Value2","Value3","Value4", "Value5` (see the missing `"` in front and in the end)

We'll have to tweak the variable a bit to fix this:

`let vConcatValues = '"' & peek('ConcatField') & '"';`

And the result then will be:

`"Value1","Value2","Value3","Value4", "Value5"`